# Form is not getting submitted on pressing Submit button

Tags: html, forms, submit

My form is not getting submitted. It was designed in Photoshop and later coded. But this works if I remove `<div class="form3 clear fix">`. But this throws the layout out. Any help is appreciated.

Image of form: http://postimg.org/image/j4h64gv59/

```
<form action="http://www.mywebsite.com/cgi-bin/cgiemail/special/hot.txt" method="post" name="form3" class="form3-form">
    <div class="form3 clearfix">
        <img class=" to_get_started_call_us_or" src="images/to_get_started_call_us_or.png" alt="To Get Started Call Us, or We’ll Call You!" width="183" height="43" title="To Get Started Call Us, or We’ll Call You!" />
        <img class=" line" src="images/line.png" alt="" width="132" height="2" />
        <input name="name" type="text" id="name" placeholder="Name" />
        <input name="email" type="text" id="email" placeholder="Email Address" />
        <input name="phone" type="text" id="phone" placeholder="Phone" />
        <input class="submit" type="submit" name="submit" alt="" value="" />
        <img class=" or_call_1-800-800-8000" src="images/or_call_1-800-800-8000.png" alt="or call 1-800-800-8000" width="165" height="44" title="or call 1-800-800-8000" />
        <div class="white_bar-holder">
            <a href="#" class=" cbbb-badge-horz"><img src="images/cbbb-badge-horz.png" alt="" width="86" height="33" /></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: At first sight that form should work. Is it possible to submit the form by pressing enter while one of the textboxes has focus?

Comment: Can you show the css that defines `.form3`?

Comment: I'm curious how one POSTs data to a .txt file...  I would have expected php or asp or jsp or something that can execute a script

Answer (score 0):

Check for the scripts linked with your page. May be the presence of code `e.preventDefault();`  (if any) for buttons and elements inside that particular `<div class="form3 clear fix>` prevents the `<form>` from submitting.